Como retornar uma lista de objetos com um atributo adicional que depende da relacao entre duas tabelas
No Backend em Java 17, Spring Boot, RDS for MySQL, tenho um sistema de RH, existe uma entidade Aluno e Recrutador, existe um recurso que permite ao Recrutador favoritar Alunos, e ver a lista de Alunos favoritos. Existe um sistema de login do Recruiter e para pesquisar a lista de todos os alunos você precisa de um token do Recruiter.
O problema é o seguinte, o front-end precisa que ao buscar por todos os Alunos ele retorne objetos jsons StudentResponse com um atributo que identifique se foi favorito pelo Recruiter ou não, por exemplo um atributo booleano favorited = true(se foi favorito) ou falso (se não tiver sido favorito).
Consegui fazer isso fazendo alguma lógica em Java, mas leva 55 segundos para retornar o json no endpoint.
Preciso que tudo isso seja mais rápido mas não sei se uma consulta SQL poderia fazer isso e não sei o que mais pode resolver.
Versão MySQL: 8.0.35
Link do banco de dados Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/7mcOWQR8
Preciso que a resposta seja um Aluno com um atributo adicional chamado favorited(boolean), assim a resposta será:
id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT CHAVE PRIMÁRIA,
atua INT,
recrutador_id BIGINT,
imagem_perfil VARCHAR(1000),
biografia VARCHAR(2000),
booleano favorito

no caso em Java será:
 classe pública StudentResponse {
       id longo privado;
       idade interna privada;
       biografia privada de String;
       private String perfilImagem;
       privado booleano favorito;

O problema é simples, basta retornar todos os alunos com um atributo "favorito" que vai depender se eles são favoritos do recrutador que está fazendo a requsição.

Você pode criar uma view no seu banco de dados com o campo adicional que você quer. Assim você terá mais performace.
